# Can CURRENT_TIMESTAMP be used as a PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, primary-key, timestamp

Can `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` be used as a `PRIMARY KEY`?

Is there a possibility that two or more different INSERTs, get the same `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: I heard of an app that was coded using timestamp as a PK, back in the 1990's. Ten years later PCs became faster and timestamps were duplicated. This caused very serious problems, as the app's functionality was highly critical. Also, PK uniqueness was not properly enforced throughout the app.

Comment: *Is there a possibility that two or more different INSERTs, get the same CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?* It's enough one query inserted 2 records for collision. So the answer for a subject question is "NO".

Comment: [n°32 of falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd want this?

Comment: @Nanne I suspect this: MySQL has a very nice handling of automatically incremented integer ids (simply an auto_increment attribute to the field). PostgreSQL has not, it has a serial type which is far lesser beautiful.

Answer (score 22):

As per the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-datetime.html), the precision of the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is microseconds. Thus, the probability of a collision is low, but possible.

Now imagine a bug which happens *very* rarely, and causes database errors. How hard is to debug it? It is a far worser bug than one which is at least deterministic.

The more broad context: you probably want to avoid these little nuances with the sequences, which is particularly annoying if you are accustomed to MySQL.

Furthermore, if you are using transactions (most web frameworks, particularly the Java ones, do!), then the timestamps will be the same inside a transaction! A demonstration:

```
postgres=# begin;
BEGIN
postgres=# select current_timestamp;
       current_timestamp       
-------------------------------
 2018-08-06 02:41:42.472163+02
(1 Zeile)

postgres=# select current_timestamp;
       current_timestamp       
-------------------------------
 2018-08-06 02:41:42.472163+02
(1 Zeile)
```

See you? Two selects, exactly the same result. I don't type so fast. ;-)

--

If you want easily IDs, avoiding the usage of the sequences, then generate some hash value from the real identifiers of the records. For example, if your database has humans, and you know that their birthdate, mother's maiden name and real name uniquely identifies them, then use an

```
md5(mother_name || '-' || given_name || '-' birthday);
```

as id. Beside that, you can use a `CreationDate` column, after what you index the table, but it is not a key (which is the id).

P.s. In general, it is a *very good practice* to make your DB so deterministic, as it is possible. I.e. *the same operation should create exactly the same change in the DB*. Any timestamp-based ID fails this important feature. What if you want to debug or simulate anything? You replay an operation and the *same object will be created with a different id*... it is really not hard to follow, and it spares a lot of work hours.

P.s.2 Anybody checking your code in the future, won't have the best opinion  seeing timestamp-generated ids, on the reasons above.

Comment: Even if you are not using transactions, you are in fact using transactions (because Postgres doesn't have a no-transactions mode, it just has autocommit).  So if you do an `INSERT` of multiple rows, they all get the same `current_timestamp`.  And then you have triggers...

Comment: I have heard about an app that broke because of the 2 guys had the same name and born on the same day and their mother names were identical. Ouch. If it CAN happen it WILL happen, sooner or later.

Comment: @BalazsGunics Helló :-) It was just an example. For example, in real scenarios, I think id as email address or the chosen user name (which can be registered only if it doesn't exist yet) is enough. Government tends to use some personal identification number, like 1 870728 0651. The important thing is, binding an id to a timestamp or to a random value is imho a bad practice, because it makes the DB lesser deterministic.

Comment: @BalazsGunics Beside that, two people with the same mother_name + given_name + birthday, it would cause still a deterministic error. Primary key collision due to that two transactions having inserts happened in in the same microsecond, it still a non-deterministic, and very hardly reproducable problem.

Answer (score 10):

Not really because it’s possible for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to provide two identical values for two subsequent INSERTs (or a single INSERT with multiple rows).

Use a time-based UUID instead: [uuid_generate_v1mc()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html).

Answer (score 10):

Strictly speaking: **No.** Because [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) is a *function* and only one or more table *columns* can form a [`PRIMARY KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS) constraint.

If you mean to create a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on a column with the default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, then the answer is: **Yes, you *can***. Nothing keeps you from doing it, like nothing keeps you from shooting apples from your son's head. The question still wouldn't make sense while you don't define the purpose of it. What kind of data are column and table supposed to hold? What rules are you trying to implement?

Typically, the idea is bound to run into duplicate key errors since `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a `STABLE` function returning the same value for the same transaction (the start time of the transaction). Multiple INSERTs in the same transaction are bound to collide - like other answers already illustrated. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

> Since these functions return the start time of the current
>   transaction, their values do not change during the transaction. This
>   is considered a feature: the intent is to allow a single transaction
>   to have a consistent notion of the “current” time, so that multiple
>   modifications within the same transaction bear the same time stamp.

Postgres timestamps are implemented as 8-byte integers representing up to 6 fractional digits (microsecond resolution).

**If** you are building a table that is supposed to hold no more than one row per microsecond and that condition is not going to change (something named `sensor_reading_per_microsecond`), **then** it might make sense. Duplicate rows are **supposed** to raise a duplicate key violation error. That's an exotic exception, though. And the data type `timestamptz` (not `timestamp`) would probably be preferable. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

I would still rather use a surrogate serial primary key instead. And add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the timestamp column. Fewer possible complications, not relying on implementation details of the RDBMS.

Comment: Even `sensor_reading_per_microsecond` may collide if you can't absolutely guarantee that the timing of each reading is perfectly synchronised with respect to the previous one; a sub-microsecond deviation (which is often not impossible) breaks the scheme. In general I'd still totally avoid this. (Mind you, as you've indicated, in such a case, the resulting collision may be desirable!)

Comment: @Lightness: I am in complete agreement. Your example with unintended time-shift after a rounded tiny deviation illustrates another caveat.